# Is the package version specified in the pubspec.yaml included anywhere in the compiled output?

Tags: dart

Is it possible to programmatically access the version of my app once it's been compiled to javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't supported yet.

Some related open issues:

- http://dartbug.com/21020
- http://dartbug.com/16370